# PDO nao retorna erro mesmo em um bloco try catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Estava tentando cadastrar em um banco mysql utilizando PDO. Não cadastrava mas mesmo assim eu nao tinha um retorno de erro apesar do bloco `try` `catch`. Descobri mais tarde que o erro era o tamanho da coluna `telefone`, no banco era 11, mas estava passando uma string com tamanho 13. Como Fazer a impressao do erro neste caso ja que o `try` `catch` não faz isso?

```
<?php
function save($dados){
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=projetocadastro;", "root", "123456");
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tb_clientes(nome, cpf, telefone, email, nascimento, estado, cidade, bairro, rua, numero) VALUES (:nome, :cpf, :telefone, :email, :nascimento, :estado, :cidade, :bairro, :rua, :numero);';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $dados['nome']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':cpf', $dados['cpf']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':telefone', $dados['telefone']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $dados['email']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':nascimento', $dados['dtnasc']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':estado', $dados['estado']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':cidade', $dados['cidade']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':bairro', $dados['bairro']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':rua', $dados['rua']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':numero', $dados['numero']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }finally{
        $pdo = null;
    }
}
save($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altere o [error mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) da sua classe PDO para `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=projetocadastro;", 
    "root",
    "123456",
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
);
```

Comment: Pode remover essa aspas solta na penultima linha?

Comment: Pode, foi um erro de digitação